# iPhone and iPad screen resolution

Tags: iphone, ipad

I m developing a universal app.I want to know will the screen resolutions (320 * 480) for iphone and (768 *1024 )in iPad will work for all iphone's (iPhone 3g,iPhone4 etc) and all iPads.Because based on these screen resolutions I m setting textField's, UILabel's width in both iPhone and iPad.Will these work for retinas and nonretinas ?

Answer (score 15):

Retina iPhones and iPads use the same coordinate system as non-Retina devices.  Presently all iPads have a logical coordinate space of 768x1024, and all iPhones except the iPhone 5 have a logical coordinate space of 320x480. Your code should work fine on both Retina and non-Retina devices.

On an iPhone 5, your app will be shown with black bars at the top of the screen unless you tell iOS that you want to use the full screen by including a Default.png for the extended screen resolution.

You can check the screen resolution with `[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]`. This value will be the same on Retina and non-Retina devices.  You can detect a Retina device by checking the value of `[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]`; the value here is the number of physical pixels per unit of logical coordinate space (1.0 for non-Retina, 2.0 for Retina).

Comment: Yes I have placed the same 768x1024 for iPad and 320x480(for iPhone).It means no other cordinates for retina and nonretina .Does it make difference in orientations (portrait and landscape) ?And what about iPhone5 ?Should I change the code again for its specifications?

Comment: You've got a lot of distinct questions here.  I suggest you start by reading Apple's documentation on UIViewController: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html, which covers many of these topics.

Answer (score 1):

`UIKit` and `CoreGraphics` work with points rather than pixels.

Both the retina and non-retina devices have the same number of points, but a different amount of pixels. This means that the same point values can mean a different pixel value on different devices.

To answer your question, yes the same layout `UILabel` widths will display the same on retina and non retina devices.

From the Apple Developer Documentation :

`In iOS, all coordinate values and distances are specified using floating-point values in units referred to as points. The measurable size of a point varies from device to device and is largely irrelevant. The main thing to understand about points is that they provide a fixed frame of reference for drawing.`

Have a look at the Points vs. Pixels section in the View Programming Guide:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH2-SW15

Answer (score -1):

You can always use the capabilities to get the OS and do what you need to your interface.

```
var pattern:RegExp = /iphone5/i; 
var str:String = Capabilities.os; 

if (str.search(pattern)==0)
{
    trace('iPhone5 Detected. Alter height.');
}else{
   trace('No need to change dimensions if developing at 960x640');
}
```